# Find rows by multiple keys and values from json column in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, select

I have a table which has a json column and I want to get only the rows that has an specific key an value into the json like this:

here is the an example of the value from that column when I do a simple select query like:

```
select my_atribute from displays;
```

result:

```
   {"key": "unit_type", "value": "Tablet", "display_name": "Unit Type"}
   {"key": "pack_type", "value": "Packet", "display_name": "Pack Type"}
   {"key": "units_in_pack", "value": "60", "display_name": "Units in Pack"}
   {"key": "item_unit", "value": "", "display_name": "Item unit"}
   {"key": "item_size", "value": "1", "display_name": "Item Size"}
   {"key": "details", "value": "", "display_name": "Details"}
   {"key": "slug", "value": "otc7087", "display_name": "Slug"}
```

I want only the rows that have  "key" like "slug"or "details" and "display_name" like "Item unit" or "Details"

I've tried the code bellow:

```
WITH my_table(jsonblob) AS (VALUES ((select my_atribute from displays) :: jsonb))
SELECT elem ->> 'value'
FROM my_table
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(jsonblob) elem
WHERE ((elem ->> 'key') in ('slug', 'details'))
  and ((elem ->> 'display_name') in ('Item unit', 'Details'));
```

and here is the message that I get:
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: Have you tried something a little simpler like `SELECT * FROM displays WHERE my_attribute->>'key' IN ('slug', 'details')...` ?

Comment: @jmelesky i've tried right now. It works! Thanks! But... there's a way that I pass the parameter and consider all values ? something like: SELECT * FROM displays WHERE my_attribute->>'key' IN ('%%')...

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I'm not familiar with the library you're using.